# How to insert value to MySQL table

Tags: php, android, mysql

How to after Android connect PHP, insert value to SQL table?

I want to use Android post value to PHP, then PHP can receive value and insert to.

But now I have problem, I don't know why can't insert to.

This is my Android code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView t;
    //
    String url = "http://00.00.00.00/Insert.php";

    //thread
    Handler mHandle; //manager
    HandlerThread mThread;//worker
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     
        //create table using CreateTable.php
        mThread = new HandlerThread("CreateTable");//
        mThread.start();//worker stand by
        mHandle = new Handler (mThread.getLooper());//look for worker using Handle manager
        mHandle.post(CreateTable);//give work for worker
    }
    //
    private Runnable CreateTable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //connect php
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost method = new HttpPost(url);
            //send value to 
            List< NameValuePair> vars=new ArrayList< NameValuePair>();
            vars.add(new BasicNameValuePair("number","abc"));
            try {
                method.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(vars,HTTP.UTF_8));
                Log.e("TAG","Send to php");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

and this is my php code

```
<?php   
 $dbhost = 'localhost';   
 $dbuser = 'root';   
 $dbpass = '';   
 $dbname = 'androidhive';   

 $number = $_POST['number'];//$number from android

 $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die('Error with MySQL connection');

  mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
  mysql_select_db($dbname);   
  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1(Username,Password,Role) VALUES('number', 'number', 'number')");
?>
```

Comment: If you're using Android Hive as a source of tutorials, please don't - their PHP examples seem to contain SQL injections, and they won't reply to tweets asking them to fix such security issues.

Comment: `$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1(Username,Password,Role) VALUES('$number', '$number', '$number')");`

Comment: @Frank thx ,After I change,still fail ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find my mistake,and correct php

```
<?php   
    header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8"); 
    $conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'password', 'databasename');
    $conn->set_charset('utf8');

    $number = $_POST['number'];
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1(Username,Password,Role) VALUES('$number', '$number', '$number')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "insert to table successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
    $conn->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call execute method on HttpClient.

```
httpClient.execute(postRequest);
```